# What are the most common issues with older laptops running latest software (with focus on OS)

Tags: windows, laptop, home-office

I have an oldie - laptop DELL E6400 - that I want to give my mother-in-law as a replacement for the desktop she was using in her work (she has her own business, so office and personal use, but nothing fancy), which in turn breathed it's last a few weeks back (Dell GX240 or earlier).

Laptop originally came with Vista Business, but I never even once booted it with that OS. I had Pro versions of every OS that came later - 7, 8, 8.1, 10 installed and used on it.
There are drivers available for Windows 7 for this laptop.

So on one hand Windows 7 would be the least problematic option, but on the other hand it will not be supported for long by Microsoft, and drivers already are not developed anymore by vendors. That would not be a problem with just office use, but small business owners need to count their money and I can easily see it used in home. Therefore there is a need to look at other WIndows versions, but here is where it gets complicated.

From my own experience there are certain applications that while giving impressions of simple program, in fact rely heavily on either (or both) functions of the Operating system available only - or greatly improved - in newer versions and/or devices that offer some additional functionalities beyond basic.

To further explain what it means using real-life examples: laptop in question has a Powershare option for USB port, which means that you can use it as a powerbank for any usb-charge-compatible device. While you would not take it on a hike in the mountains, I routinely had it on vacations and whenever it was nearby I used it to charge all my stuff. I used is as a backup for pics and vids from said holidays - 1080p means that even 128GB SD will be filled quickly. I used it to boost wifi signal by running Connectify in repeater mode so that we could use our mobiles while vacationing abroad (why pay for calls to family when you can use whatsapp?).
I used it to convert videos of my kid I made on the beach so that it can be sent via email to her grandma to swoon over her ingenuity with a sand beach shovel...

But upgrade to a newer Windows version and suddenly Connectify doesn't work because driver doesn't support hardware function of the wifi adapter. GPU cannot be used anymore to do fast conversion because DirectX version supported by this newer windows does not support older DX implementation in the VGA adapter. And so on.
Which is very annoying, because even if this laptop is 9 years old, it is - in current configuration - at least as powerful as any new laptop you can buy for £250 while worth about half that.

I think there is a reason why around 50% of computers used in business worldwide still run on windows XP.

SO the question is: how difficult average user will find using old hardware with newer software? How probable is the situation when after another update (be it windows, driver, installed software) something either doesn't work properly anymore. Or at all. On the other hand - what would be the strong points of running newest software on old systems? Platform stability and security is obvious, so how important that would be in office/personal use and would that outbalance some loss of existing functionality? Virtually no computer running Windows 7 was a victim of this year's ransomware rampage, so that is a big selling point, but is there something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [miroxlav](https://superuser.com/users/287473/miroxlav) for pointing in the right direction.

Answer to the question is quite simple, if reasoning for it is... to say it's complicated is understatement of the year.And it goes like this:

### Laptop gives best possible performance and best possible experience with the operating system it was designed for.

It should be possible to upgrade the OS to next version without much of an issue, but this often applies to Windows 8 and later only. Jump from Windows Vista or Windows 7 is next to impossible without major issues due to obsolete technology. 5+ years is long enough to see several generations of hardware to come to pass and there's nothing to be done about it.

To extend older laptop's relevancy one needs to upgrade components as much as possible: SSD, new BT/GSM module, newest possible WiFi adapter. But while it will extend it's usable lifetime - somewhat - there's nothing to be done with SATAII controller, Penryn platform and NVS160 (for which drivers are no longer updated).

That you need to upgrade OS is basically a must. Software development companies will follow the life cycle of the OS as they cannot justify maintenance for their products designed for platforms their manufacturer no longer supports. But you may not be able to upgrade due to lack of support for older CPUs and chipsets on newer OSes at some point at all.

**Bottom line.**

From my POV old laptop is a perfect gift for beginners. It will force them to work quite hard to get best possible performance, which will always is invaluable experience for any PC user.

Other than that? Electronic photo frame, print server, network file share, network DVD drive and remote desktop server (for access your stuff from any place in the world) host all-in-one is the best use I came up with for old laptop.

Answer (score -1):

Please what exactly do you expect to be the answer? Do you think there is a clear answer for "which system will be most reliable and easiest to use, and will have least compatibility issues with newer software"? This is unanswerable. But I am still answering with important points to consider:

- Mind that Windows updates are ever-growing until given version of Windows is supported. This is by design. So if the machine has 256 GB HDD, it can get a problems with disk space in Windows 8 or Windows 10. Do not partition such a drive.
- Applications won't support older operating systems forever. Quickly evaluate what applications do you need and what is their oldest supported OS version. Based on this observe how quickly is each of them abandoning old OS versions which should give you some estimate what OS version to prefer if the planned life time is X years.

Try to balance these factors.

---

Edit:

- As of WhatsApp, it [currently works on Windows 8+](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/web/26000010/).
- Regarding old peripherals, you can put Windows XP or 7 to virtual machine into given computer and use them from there. The scissors is opening, you won't be able to run scanner from 2008 on Windows 10. This is normal. (I don't like it, too, and I am still running scanner from year 2000 that way.)

Comment: I'm a DA, DBA, and a BI specialist, so I know my way around computers, I know how to take care of my machine, software and hardware wise (including windows updates etc). I know that Windows 7 EOL is 3 years away... I know that WIndows 7 will quickly bloat to 100GB folder...And so on and so forth... I thought that putting "I'm an IT professional" takes care of all that... But everything else you point out is so far outside my experience and usable knowledge (usable for me). I use Whatsapp because my wife uses it, not because I like it. I can't put myself in place of average user.

Comment: I will edit my question to better reflect my expectations, but how far should I go before it becomes so detailed it will then be really useless? How much time I can invest into investigating something someone else might have already researched? Thanks for pointers and your time. Appreciated. It will be taken into account.

Comment: @AcePL – thank your for clarification. Then I am putting a close vote on your question as off-topic. This type of questions (software recommendations) is not supported at the [su]. (We have to live with fact that sites on Stack Exchange network regulate types of allowed questions.) Maybe you can ask *modified* question at Software Recommendations SE (but please see [help](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there which indicates where should be the focus of the question).

Comment: What I'm asking for is definitely not for a recommendation. More like for user experience with new software on old machines, which definitely is within a scope of SuperUser, not to mention a topic that, if not already, will be a quite hot question soon, with ever-increasing number of computers in an average household... If I rework the question to reflect that will it make it more acceptable?

Comment: @AcePL – I researched WhatsApp for you. It took only single Google search. So Windows 8 minimum.  Do you think you need any other help with searching?

Answer (score -2):

Across all aspects the most compatible(ms) OS and easy to user at least the easiest to get use to is windows 7. I have the Latitude E6410 with W7x64 it runs fine. I did however upgrade the HDD to a 1TB but thats because I partitioned my HDD to have a (F11) recovery and hidden backup segment but thats besides the point.

Comment: WIndows 7 will not be supported for long. E6400 is already 9 years old, it might work for another 9... But there are already some programs that are no longer supported on W7 (even if still compatible). Not to mention drivers. So while I generally agree with you, the devil is in the details...

Comment: Well for any modern compatibility, yes this laptop is old, so it won't be compatible for a lot longer but how long will your moms business have to rely on this laptop? Windows 10 isn't ready. Windows 8.1 isn't "great" and Vista is nonsense. Maybe Ubuntu instead? run windows applications using wine or something similar. I get that this has a learning curve.